# Is there a matlab function to initiate a program at a preset time?

Tags: matlab

Is there a matlab function to initiate a program at a preset time?

for example, I want to run the script runmyfile.m at 14h00 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a [TIMER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f9-38055.html) object that calls your code, and then use the [STARTAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/startat.html) function to launch your script at a given time.

For example, if you want to run a script called `runmyfile.m`:

```
t1=timer('TimerFcn','runmyfile');
startat(t1,'14:00:00');
```